# Can't mount card reader

Tags: usb, mount, card-reader

I have a card from a camera. The card itself seems fine because when I put it back into the camera I can see the pictures.

When I plug the card reader into the pc, its red light lights up but the "options" panel does not open.

`dmesg | tail` output:

```
[1736132.098810] usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=048d, idProduct=1336
[1736132.098819] usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[1736132.098824] usb 2-1.1: Product: Mass Storage Device
[1736132.098828] usb 2-1.1: Manufacturer: Generic   
[1736132.098833] usb 2-1.1: SerialNumber: 00000000000006
[1736132.099467] usb-storage 2-1.1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[1736132.099704] scsi host7: usb-storage 2-1.1:1.0
[1736133.400514] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  Storage Device   0.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[1736133.401608] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[1736133.961082] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

`lsusb` output:

```
Bus 002 Device 023: ID 048d:1336 Integrated Technology Express, Inc. SD/MMC Cardreader
```

`cat /proc/partitions` output:

```
major minor  #blocks  name

  11        0    1048575 sr0
```

The only thing which isn't one of the sda HD partition is sr0. So I tried mounting it:

```
sudo mount /dev/sr0 /media/disk
```

This gave me this:

```
mount: /media/disk: no medium found on /dev/sr0.
```

I also tried

```
sudo mount /dev/sdc /media/disk
```

which gave me:

```
mount: /media/disk: no medium found on /dev/sdc.
```

But I didn't expect it to function, I think I need an sdc1.

Could the card reader itself be faulty? It's the first time I try this one.

Comment: I read that I could disable ehci_hcd module. It seems to have fixed the problem for someone (but on archlinux). Any ideas about this please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you're getting these drive names from but have you tried manually mounting it???

To find all connected drives you can run something like:

`sudo fdisk -l`

Then, find the drive you are looking for... You can then mount it by running something like:

`sudo mount drive_you_found_here  location_you_want_to_mount_to_here`

I hope this solves your problem, but again I wasn't sure where you were getting these drive names from...

Comment: sudo fdisk -l
                                                                                                      
Disk /dev/sda: 465,8 GiB                                

/dev/sda1            2048  52430847  52428800    25G 1c Hidden W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sda2  *     52430848 443140095 390709248 186,3G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       443140096 719883287 276743192   132G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       719884286 976771071 256886786 122,5G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       719884288 976771071 256886784 122,5G 83 Linux

Comment: Thank you NerdOfCode. The drive names? Well, if I'm not mistaken, anything sda is on the internal hard disk and plugged-in stuff becomes sdc. I have no idea what sr0 is.

Comment: In my experience, most plugin drives are named `/dev/sda[a-z][A-Z]`... @AlainReve

Comment: I've also seen some sdb.

Comment: But anyways, do you see the drive you're looking for and have you tried mounting it? @AlainReve

Comment: I can see it with dmesg. It's an sdc. But it doesn't mount.

Comment: Have you tried mounting on something like `/mnt`... What is the output when you try to mount on this directory?

Comment: "no medium found on /dev/sdc"